# export and import data from wordpress website to another wordpress website is not working

Tags: wordpress

I have an old wordpress website using an old theme and I have developed a new website with new theme and new settings

Now I am facing problem in moving posts from old website to new website

I have tried the following :

Wordpress Dashboard -> tools -> export and downloaded the file and then go to new wordpress website and in from Wordpress Dashboard -> tools -> imported -> blogger importer and uploaded the file and it show me success message

but when I back to check the posts I did not find it

can anyone advice please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to install the WordPress importer to import data exported from WordPress. The blogger importer will only work for data exported from Blogger.

See `Tools > Import > WordPress`